# Use partial derivatives to find the following dz/ds

Tags: calculus

Find partial derivatives of $z = \tan(u/v)$ where
\begin{align*}
u &= 2s + 3t,\\
v &= 3s-2t,\\
\frac{dz}{ds} &= \frac{dz}{du}\frac{du}{ds} + \frac{dz}{dv}\frac{dv}{ds}\\
&= \sec^2\left(\frac uv\right)\frac{2v}{v^2} + \sec^2\left(\frac uv\right)\left(\frac{-3u}{v^2}\right)\\
&= \sec^2\left(\frac uv\right)\frac 2v + \sec^2\left(\frac uv\right)\left(\frac{-3u}{v^2}\right)\\
&\cdots
\end{align*}
Is the final simplified value an actual number? because I'm getting 
$\sec^2\left(\dfrac{2s+3t}{3s-2t}\right)\left(\dfrac{-13t}{(3s-2t)^2}\right)$
for $dz/ds$.

Answer (score 1):

Given that $$z = \tan \frac uv$$
Let us first find the partial derivatives of $z$, $\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}$

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial z}{\partial u} &= \frac 1v\sec^2 \frac uv\\
\frac{\partial z}{\partial v} &= \frac {-u}{v^2}\sec^2 \frac uv
\end{align*}
$$

Following that, let us find the first order partial derivative of $u$ and $v$ w.r.t. $s$ and $t$, respectively. Note that this gives us 4 different first derivatives, namely
$\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}$, $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$, $\frac{\partial v}{\partial s}$ and $\frac{\partial s}{\partial t}$
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial s} &= 2\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} &= 3\\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial s} &= 3\\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} &= -2\\
\end{align*}
$$

All you need to do right now is to perform the chain rule multiplication to find the partial derivative of $z$ w.r.t. $s$ and $t$.

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial z}{\partial s} &= \frac{\partial z}{\partial u} \times \frac{\partial u}{\partial s} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial v} \times \frac{\partial v}{\partial s}\\
&= \frac 2v\sec^2 \frac uv + \frac {-3u}{v^2}\sec^2 \frac uv\\
&= \frac 2{3s-2t}\sec^2 \begin{pmatrix}\frac {2s+3t}{3s-2t}\end{pmatrix} - \frac {3(3s+3t)}{(3s-2t)^2}\sec^2 \begin{pmatrix}\frac {2s+3t}{3s-2t}\end{pmatrix}\\
\end{align*}
$$

You can perform the same substitution to obtain the $\frac{\partial z}{\partial t}$. Note that this function has 2 different partial derivatives, one w.r.t. $s$ and one w.r.t. $t$. The question should specify which variable it wants to take derivatives from.